# Generic Method which take class as a parameter

Tags: vb.net

I have two different class and want to use class as a parameter in Notify function.
====Code======================
' Mail Class notification parameters

```
Friend Class MailClass   
         Friend NotifyHost As String   
         Friend NotifyPort As String    
End Class
```

' FTP Class notification parameters

```
  Friend Class FtpClass       
    Friend NotifyHost As String     
    Friend NotifyPort As String        
    End Class     


Friend Class ProcessNotification      
    'Notify on FTP Specified Email            
     Private Sub btnMailNotiFy_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As     System.EventArgs)       
    Notify (ByRef mailAccount as MailClass)      
    End Sub 

    'Notify on FTP Specified Email
    Private Sub btnFTPNotiFy_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Notify (ByRef ftpAccount as FtpClass)
    End Sub

    ' Generic method to use for multiple class
    Private Sub Notify(NO Idea ??)
    ' ## Please Help ### 
    End Sub
End Class
```

How to make Notify method Generic ?

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235246.aspx) has been a part of .Net since 2.0.
Are you looking for something like this?

```
Private Sub Notify(Of T as Class)(ByVal agr as T)
' do stuff
End Sub
```

**Update**

Following our discussion in the comments, you need to create an interface that will specify all the properties and methods you want to use inside your generic method, and then use it as a generic constraint:

```
Friend Interface IMyInrteface
    NotifyHost As String   
    NotifyPort As String  
End Interface

Private Sub Notify(Of T as IMyInrteface)(ByRef agr as T)
' do stuff
End Sub
```

Of course, all the classes you send to this method must implement the interface:

```
Friend Class MailClass   
    Implements IMyInrteface
    Friend NotifyHost As String   
    Friend NotifyPort As String    
End Class 

Friend Class FtpClass       
    Implements IMyInrteface
    Friend NotifyHost As String     
    Friend NotifyPort As String        
End Class
```

Comment: I tried this but getting error said 'NotifyHost is not a member of T'

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code now. Also, I see the Notify message should accept T ByRef and not ByVal.

Comment: but if i use Notify(of T as Class)(ByRef account as T) , can not use account.NotifyHost, get error said NotifyHost is not a member of T. i want to use generic method for multiple class as a parameter how can i access class property using your code ??

Comment: So i have to implement Notify Function in both Class with same functionality ?

Comment: No, the point of having an interface is that it only defines the signature. the implementation can be anything you want.

Comment: Yes I know but i am using same functionality for both the class just parameter values is different. we can  not use this C# code "public void Swap<T>(ref T input1, ref T input2) where T : class { }" in vb.net reference http://dotnetpattern.com/csharp-generic-methods  I tried to use Notify(Of T as Class) but cannot access class properties

Comment: If the only difference is in values of parametets why do you have different classes?

Comment: That's true but my classes also have many more properties then just notification. anyways i make new generic class called notification used it for both classes. I just want to know is vb.net has something like C# has here http://dotnetpattern.com/csharp-generic-methods. thanks for your help @ Zohar